# How to share text in installed social media in windows phone 8?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am developing windows phone application using
Windows Phone SDK 8.0 and Visual Studio 2012.

In my application i want to share text to installed social media of phone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [ShareStatusTask](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/microsoft.phone.tasks.sharestatustask(v=vs.105).aspx) for this:

```
ShareStatusTask sst= new ShareStatusTask();
sst.Status = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet";
sst.Show();
```

See [How to use the share status task for Windows Phone 8](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh394027(v=vs.105).aspx) for more details. You may also be interested in the [ShareLinkTask](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/microsoft.phone.tasks.sharelinktask(v=vs.105).aspx) and [ShareMediaTask](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/microsoft.phone.tasks.sharemediatask(v=vs.105).aspx).

Comment: Hi Rob Caplan - MSFT  thanks for your reply, How do i check in emulator?, it is not showing any error.

Comment: for this you, must have Windows Phone device :)